# Add-On Dev: Is there a way to detect when my panel is open?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is there a way to execute code when the side panel of my add-on is expanded and collapsed? Or any way to detect changes in visibility of the body of the side panel?

I would like to use a modal operator to catch user events, but I don't want it to run continuously unless the user is actively managing the scene with my add-on. Would there be a way to only run a modal operator while my side panel is visible?